# Названия профессий

Tags: этимология

Ясно, что пахарь пашет, доярка доит корову, а швея шьет. Но почему тот, кто вытачивает детали на станке, называется токарь, тот, кто меняет трубы - слесарь, а тот, что работает с деревом — плотник?

Comment: Тот, кто вытачивает (точит) детали - токарь. А кто точит ножи - точильщик ;-))

Comment: У меня лично с точильщиком ассоциируется только жук-точильщик :-)

Comment: Ходили они (не жуки) по улицам, кричали "Ножи точу". Еще тогда старьевщики были. Но очень давно. Даже не могу сказать, сама ли я их видела или по рассказам родителей помню?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**СЛЕСАРЬ**

От нов.-в.-нем. Schlosser, из Schloss (Schloß) «замок». Использованы данные Толкового словаря русского языка с включением сведений о происхождении слов (2007); см. Список литературы.

**ТОКАРЬ**

Происходит от общеслав гл. точить; ср.: русск. токарь, белор., укр. токар, польск. tokarz и т. п. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.

**ПЛОТНИК**

От плот «забор», плету́. Ср. др.-русск. плотъ «ограда, плетень», оплотъ «ограда, стена, забор; предел», др.-чешск. plesti рlоt «плести ограду», ср. нов.-в.-нем. Wand «стена»: winden «вить». Русск. плотник — уже в Домостр. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера; см. Список литературы.